# Make a Session using Apex code

Tags: apex, login, session

I am wondering if there is any out-of-the-box functionality to make a Session for a specific User using Apex code.

What I mean is this: I would create an Apex method, pass a UserID as a parameter, inside this method create an active session for the UserID and return a valid and active SessionID.

I need this method to avoid SOAP login() method and/or Connected App.

Thanks

Comment: You can't create a Session without authenticating in some way or another, but it doesn't have to be by calling `login()`. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @DavidReed Basically I want to expose an Apex REST method and when the external system calls it, I want to return a bunch of data and also a valid SessionID in order to avoid a further call to obtain it. Thanks!

Comment: Your remote system has to have a session Id to call the method anyway, unless you're exposing it to the unauthenticated world via a Site - which would be a *terrible* idea.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, the external system uses a Connected App in order to call this Apex REST method. The SessionID I would generate in this Apex method is related to another user.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of your use case?